# Document Interaction Controller on Titanium

Tags: objective-c, titanium, appcelerator, uidocumentinteraction

Is there a way to toggle the DocumentInteractionController on Titanium
i'm not finding it in any way

i think this is what i need

```
- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL) fileURL
    usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController =
        [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;

    return interactionController;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`Ti.UI.iOS.createDocumentViewer()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.DocumentViewer). That API uses `UIDocumentInteractionController` under the covers.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});
win.open();

// Download a PDF.
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'casestudy_bracket.pdf'),
    client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function() {
        // Open a doc viewer.
        var docViewer = Ti.UI.iOS.createDocumentViewer({
            url: file.nativePath
        });
        docViewer.show({ animated: true });
    },
    onerror: function() {
        alert('Well, shoot.')
    }
});
client.open('GET', 'http://www.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/casestudy_bracket.pdf');
client.file = file;
client.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer this it helps you.

In this blog there is source code is available to open document in ios-documentviewer.

[Appcelerator Blog](http://dharmikon.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-use-ios-documentviewer.html)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @ kleopatra : Thanks for your instruction :).